# Is it possible to see my site's real IP address if I'm using a CDN like CloudFlare?

Tags: ip-address, cloudflare, reverse-proxy

CloudFlare acts as a reverse proxy and caches site content.

Is it possible to see my site's real IP address if I'm using a CDN like CloudFlare?

When I check my site's IP address using a lookup service, I get CloudFlare's IP address.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few smart ways, so in theory it is **sometimes** possible, but only with a **bad admin configuration**. In practice it's about **impossible**.

For example, try getting the IP address of a site's DNS records like: `cpanel.domain`, `webmail.domain`, etc... Maybe they'll point to the real IP address if they're not proxied through CloudFlare.

CloudFlare wasn't made for nothing - it's an anti-DDoS service and a CDN, which will also protect a website by protecting it's IP address.

Comment: thanks for your input, i already tried all moethods but it looke quite difficult for me to get the specific site's ip address, i didnt knew hiding server real ip was one of the services provided by cloudflare. i tried direct and few others sub-domains.,

Comment: Using CloudFlare means that our IPs are going to show in a lookup against the domain (we're a reverse proxy).

Comment: @damoncloudflare Nice, official CloudFlare's here too.